# Adding uncited work to natbib bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'd like to add a reference to my bibliography made with `natbib` in LaTeX. I've been citing a few different newspapers, but since there is no easy format in `natbib` for newspapers, I have been citing these sources manually in the footnotes. Since my bibliography file (made with BibDesk) does not include these newspaper references, the final bibliography excludes them.  How can I manually add these newspapers to the final bibliography?

I have been adding usualy citations with the following code:

```
\footnote{~\citealt[12]{Author}.}
```

This refers back to an entry for Author in my bibliography file from BibDesk

But, when I want to cite a newspapers, I've just been using the following code:

```
\footnote{~\textit{Newspaper Title}, Date.}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to add something manually to the bibliography. The proper way is to add an item to your `bib` file. Of course it is sometimes hard to chose the right entry type. But when you cite a newspaper, you might actually cite an article that has ann author, is on a specific page, and so on, so the `@article` type might fit. As a last resort, you might chose the `@other` type, where you are free to add any information.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the @Misc type? It is for citing "strange" stuff.
Also, it is possible to add stuff to the bibliography by using \nocite{....}. A handy trick for printing out all your entries is \nocite{*}.